# How to allow requests to items underneath an JSON endpoint

Tags: sxa, presentation

We are using a JSON based contentstore for one of our projects. We are working with Sitecore 9.0 and SXA for generation JSON documents for our content stores. Now our client asks if we can allow calls to children of an endpoint instead of the end-points itself. Is this possible, and if so, how?

for example we have: this

- Endpoint

  - Group

    - Key
    - Value

the client wants to do direct requests to: /endpoint/group and wants to retrieve its sub key value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that we were using the wrong placeholder settings for the relevant JSON Layouts.

Changing this by using then presentation item on the ribbon and edit the layout details and edit the JSON List control to use the right placeholder (json instead of main), the issue was resolved.

[image: Final Layout for the JSON List]
[image: Control properties for the JSON List]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you expected but take a look bellow. For the following structure:

[image]

I was able to generate such JSON:

[image]

Using just Json Content rendering with following Rendering Variant:

[image]

You can modify the query as you need...